# Error in compile ShowcaseViewSample

Tags: android, eclipse, compiler-errors, showcaseview

I downlaoded ShowcaseView Library from github and imported this on eclipse. I downloaded ActionBarSherlock-4.4.0 and imported it as well.

I also added ShowcaseView Library and ActionBarSherlock-4.4.0 to a sample project and didn't get any error on this, but when I click on `run as android application`, after long time I get:

`Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Java heap space`

and app doesn't run.

Meanwhile I get this in the console:

`Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.ibex.nestedvm.util.Sort$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.`

Please help me.

Comment: Do you google before asking questions? This question has been asked so many times with lots and lots of helpful links and articles and answers to that. You should just search before asking every question here.
https://www.google.ie/search?q=Conversion+to+Dalvik+format+failed:+Unable+to+execute+dex:+Java+heap+space&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gws_rd=cr&ei=zYmQU6-FDJKv7AaukICIAw

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem to do with the robolectric JAR included in the project. Remove the JAR (in the libs folder of the library) and it should compile OK.

Comment: library need the jars and when i delete them error in library